# why react router url changes but component does not load in my nested router app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

react-router URL changes but the component do not load. my app content lots off the nested router.
see my layout
[image: react app layout]

in this app my main two problem 
1. redirect
2. component not load

see this gif video what is my problem

[why react router url changes but component does not load in my nested router app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFsb1.jpg)

I share gif video because of my gif size big than 2mb.
in this gif video, you see when clicking on the logout button than not redirect.
second when clicking on the signup button my app not redirect.

plz tell me what is my problem

Comment: plase just share your code, not jpgs

Comment: I share video with gif because of my app to large so that

Comment: I understand but still, it is better to share code than images/videos due to copy/pa possibility, etc. and you can get more interaction and help from others in this way. try to share the part of the code you think might be has the problem

Answer (score 1):

You just have to wrap the components inside withRouter.

```
<Route exact path="/mypath" component={withRouter(MyComponent)} />
```